# Fortran 90 error using abs()

Tags: fortran, gfortran

On using Fortran 90 I have encountered an error in the following part

```
if(abs(pic1(1,j,1).eq.fitra(i))) fitcrv(j)=fitmax(j)
       1
```

with the error being

> Error: 'a' argument of 'abs' intrinsic at (1) must be a numeric type

Could you please help?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the stuff passed to abs() is

Comment: You have a `)` in the wrong place: the argument to `ABS` is logical.

Comment: Although, I should probably say that this would be a better question if you could convert it into a short fully stand-alone lump of code.  Like Trudbert suggests, having declarations and the like would be good.

Comment: You know you can use `==` instead of `.eq.` nowadays. [Just saying](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_control).

Comment: I think .eq. is better actually. More clear, and less chance of mistaken it with =

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with using `abs()` but with using logical expressions. As already pointed out by francescalus you are taking absolute value of `pic1(1,j,1).eq.fitra(i)` which does not make sense in fortran (the value is either `true` or `false` and cannot be put in absolute value). Matlab for instance would convert it to integer and happily give you `abs(1)`, which would be `1`. You are lucky the fortran compiler does not do that and stops right away, such a bug would be very difficult to detect.

You probably intended to do `abs(pic1(1,j,1)) .eq. fitra(i)`.

Comment: @francescalus True in principle but then there would be another problem that `abs` of whatever never evaluates to a logical expression ... well unless `abs` was overloaded as well ... uff, this sounds crazy.

Comment: Indeed: my comment was not entirely serious.